# Raspberry Pi will not shutdown/reboot

Tags: debian, raspbian-wheezy

So all of a sudden my Pi running Debian wont shutdown. I have to hard reset it for it to go down. I recently just added a script to check if the wlan0 has a connection.

I have updated the Pi but to no luck.

Any ideas?

```
fenlig@Green ~ $ sudo reboot
[sudo] password for fenlig:

Broadcast message from root@Green (pts/0) (Tue Jun 10 00:54:33 2014):

The system is going down for reboot NOW!
fenlig@Green ~ $ tail -f 5 /var/log/syslog
tail: cannot open `5' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: cannot open `/var/log/syslog' for reading: Permission denied
fenlig@Green ~ $ sudo tail -f 5 /var/log/syslog
tail: cannot open `5' for reading: No such file or directory
==> /var/log/syslog <==
Jun 10 00:47:56 Green ntpd[2355]: restrict: error in address '::' on line 38. Ignoring...
Jun 10 00:47:56 Green ntpd[2355]: restrict: error in address '::1' on line 42. Ignoring...
Jun 10 00:48:01 Green /USR/SBIN/CRON[2426]: (fenlig) CMD (raspistill -q 100 -rot 270 -o /home/fenlig/www/images/image.jpg -n && convert -pointsize 60 -fill red -draw "text 100,100 '`date`'" /home/fenlig/www/images/image.jpg /home/fenlig/www/images/image.jpg)
Jun 10 00:48:01 Green /USR/SBIN/CRON[2425]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jun 10 00:54:33 Green shutdown[2450]: shutting down for system reboot
Jun 10 00:54:33 Green init: Switching to runlevel: 6
Jun 10 00:54:34 Green ifplugd(eth0)[1702]: Exiting.
Jun 10 00:54:35 Green ifplugd(wlan0)[1701]: Exiting.
Jun 10 00:54:40 Green /USR/SBIN/CRON[2620]: (fenlig) CMD (raspistill -q 100 -rot 270 -o /home/fenlig/www/images/image.jpg -n && convert -pointsize 60 -fill red -draw "text 100,100 '`date`'" /home/fenlig/www/images/image.jpg /home/fenlig/www/images/image.jpg)
Jun 10 00:54:40 Green /USR/SBIN/CRON[2619]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jun 10 00:55:01 Green /USR/SBIN/CRON[2632]: (fenlig) CMD (raspistill -q 100 -rot 270 -o /home/fenlig/www/images/image.jpg -n && convert -pointsize 60 -fill red -draw "text 100,100 '`date`'" /home/fenlig/www/images/image.jpg /home/fenlig/www/images/image.jpg)
Jun 10 00:55:01 Green /USR/SBIN/CRON[2631]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Comment: do you back up your images? I asked because if may help you diagnose your issue by knowing what you did between the last successful back up and now. I know that it may be not the answer you are looking for but I have gone mad diagnosing these types of issues (because I am novice with Linux). Sometimes its easier to rollback to your last good backup.

Comment: Nope, I should probably learn how to :(

Comment: Well the first lesson is always the most painful. Always backup your images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a few obvious problems in your `syslog`:

1. don't put `5` in your `tail` command, the correct command would be `tail -f /var/log/syslog` (no `5` anywhere in sight)
2. install MTA for `cron` jobs to send you the feedback and error messages or redirect their output to `/dev/null`
3. disable whatever `raspistill` you have in your cron table, it is preventing your RPi from shutting down

yeah, and there's something fishy is going on with your `/var/log/syslog` itself, it should never require `sudo` to access the file, check if permissions and ownership are correct:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 9409 Jun 10 12:15 /var/log/syslog
```